# cannot be able to produce proper tree structured output using self referencing using django rest framework

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, self-reference

I have below Comment model and i want to implement the comment-reply functionality and in turn send the response as JSON using django rest framework. But in the reponse im getting the records even for 'parent not equal to None' in parent node. I want all the records whose having parent value should be displayed as only children.

models.py:

'''

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField('comment')
    expression = models.ForeignKey('Expression', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='expression')
    datecreated = models.DateTimeField('date created', auto_now_add=True)
    dateupdated = models.DateTimeField('date updated', auto_now=True)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True, blank=True, related_name='replied_to')


    class META:
        verbose_name_plural = "comments"
        ordering = ['-datecreated']

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.name)
```

'''

views.py:

'''

```
class CommentViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    comments = Comment.objects.all()
    queryset = comments

    serializer_class = CommentSerializer

    @list_route()
    def roots(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        slug = kwargs.get('slug')

        expression = Expression.objects.get(author=request.user, slug=slug)
        queryset = expression.expression.filter(parent=None)
        serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

'''

serializers.py:

'''

```
class RecursiveSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    def to_representation(self, value):
        serializer = self.parent.parent.__class__(value, context=self.context)
        # data = serializer.data.filter(parent!=0)
        return serializer.data

class CommentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    '''
    Ref: http://voorloopnul.com/blog/representing-hierarchical-data-with-django-rest-framework/
    '''
    expression = serializers.CharField(required=False, read_only=True)
    replied_to = RecursiveSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        read_only_fields = ('id','datecreated', 'dateupdated',)
        fields = ('id','name','expression','datecreated','dateupdated','parent','replied_to')
```

'''

Actual Result:

'''

```
[
    {
        "id": 5,
        "name": "my new comment",
        "expression": "My new expression",
        "datecreated": "2019-04-19T15:38:23.174877+05:30",
        "dateupdated": "2019-04-19T15:38:23.174877+05:30",
        "parent": null,
        "replied_to": [
            {
                "id": 6,
                "name": "my sub comment",
                "expression": "My new expression",
                "datecreated": "2019-04-19T15:38:55.061534+05:30",
                "dateupdated": "2019-04-23T23:56:01.846904+05:30",
                "parent": 5,
                "replied_to": [
                    {
                        "id": 7,
                        "name": "my sub sub comment",
                        "expression": "My new expression",
                        "datecreated": "2019-04-19T15:42:46.981884+05:30",
                        "dateupdated": "2019-04-23T23:56:38.131256+05:30",
                        "parent": 6,
                        "replied_to": []
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 6,
        "name": "my sub comment",
        "expression": "My new expression",
        "datecreated": "2019-04-19T15:38:55.061534+05:30",
        "dateupdated": "2019-04-23T23:56:01.846904+05:30",
        "parent": 5,
        "replied_to": [
            {
                "id": 7,
                "name": "my sub sub comment",
                "expression": "My new expression",
                "datecreated": "2019-04-19T15:42:46.981884+05:30",
                "dateupdated": "2019-04-23T23:56:38.131256+05:30",
                "parent": 6,
                "replied_to": []
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 7,
        "name": "my sub sub comment",
        "expression": "My new expression",
        "datecreated": "2019-04-19T15:42:46.981884+05:30",
        "dateupdated": "2019-04-23T23:56:38.131256+05:30",
        "parent": 6,
        "replied_to": []
    }
]
```

'''

Expected Ouput:

'''

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "new comment1",
        "expression": "My new expression1",
        "datecreated": "2019-04-07T17:52:52.784429+05:30",
        "dateupdated": "2019-04-07T17:52:52.784429+05:30",
        "parent": null,
        "replied_to": []
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "name": "my new comment",
        "expression": "My new expression",
        "datecreated": "2019-04-19T15:38:23.174877+05:30",
        "dateupdated": "2019-04-19T15:38:23.174877+05:30",
        "parent": null,
        "replied_to": [
            {
                "id": 6,
                "name": "my sub comment",
                "expression": "My new expression",
                "datecreated": "2019-04-19T15:38:55.061534+05:30",
                "dateupdated": "2019-04-23T23:56:01.846904+05:30",
                "parent": 5,
                "replied_to": [
                    {
                        "id": 7,
                        "name": "my sub sub comment",
                        "expression": "My new expression",
                        "datecreated": "2019-04-19T15:42:46.981884+05:30",
                        "dateupdated": "2019-04-23T23:56:38.131256+05:30",
                        "parent": 6,
                        "replied_to": []
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
]
```

'''

Answer (score 0):

Changed the views as below:
'''

```
class CommentViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Comment.objects.all()

    serializer_class = CommentSerializer

    def list(self, request, **kwargs):
        slug = kwargs.get('slug')
        try:
            expression = Expression.objects.get(author=request.user, slug=slug)
            queryset = expression.expression.filter(parent=None)
            serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
            return Response(serializer.data)
        except Expression.DoesNotExist as err:
            return Response(data={'error':'Expression matching query does not exist.'}, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
```

'''

Now im getting desired hierarchy as below:

'''

```
[
    {
        "id": 5,
        "name": "my new comment",
        "expression": "My new expression",
        "datecreated": "2019-04-19T15:38:23.174877+05:30",
        "dateupdated": "2019-04-19T15:38:23.174877+05:30",
        "parent": null,
        "replied_to": [
            {
                "id": 6,
                "name": "my sub comment",
                "expression": "My new expression",
                "datecreated": "2019-04-19T15:38:55.061534+05:30",
                "dateupdated": "2019-04-23T23:56:01.846904+05:30",
                "parent": 5,
                "replied_to": [
                    {
                        "id": 7,
                        "name": "my sub sub comment",
                        "expression": "My new expression",
                        "datecreated": "2019-04-19T15:42:46.981884+05:30",
                        "dateupdated": "2019-04-23T23:56:38.131256+05:30",
                        "parent": 6,
                        "replied_to": []
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 8,
        "name": "new test user comment",
        "expression": "My new expression",
        "datecreated": "2019-04-24T00:43:57.939082+05:30",
        "dateupdated": "2019-04-24T00:43:57.939082+05:30",
        "parent": null,
        "replied_to": []
    }
]
```

'''